# Boundary about the Mandelbrot Set

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f_c : z \mapsto z^2+c$ and the sequence $\displaystyle \left(z_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined by $z_0=0$ and $z_{n+1}=f_c\left(z_n\right)$.
We say that $c \in M$ if the sequence $\displaystyle \left(z_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ remains bounded.

I want to prove that if it exists $p$ such that $z_{n+p}=z_n$ starting at $n_0>0$ then $c$ relies in the boundary of $M$. Is there a way to show this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c=0$ then $z_n=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but $0$ does not belong to the boundary of the Mandelbrot set. Actually $0$ is in the interior part of the Mandelbrot set.

Probably you mean the definition of [Misiurewicz point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misiurewicz_point) $c$ for which the orbit of $0$ is **strictly** pre-periodic. In that case the property is true. A proof can be found in [Etudes dynamique des polynômes complexes](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/OrsayEnglish.pdf) (english version), Chapter 8,
by Adrien Douady and John H. Hubbard. It is based on the following deep result: there is a conformal isomorphism from the exterior of the unit disk to the complement of the Mandelbrot set.

Comment: I 've read ( not all the document ) but i can't find the proof i'm looking for do you have a page reference ?